# How to add extension method to String in c#

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods

if I had the string : `string a = "Hello there"`

I wish I could do : `a.ReplaceThereSubstring()`

and to expect `a = "Hello here"`

I tried like this:

```
public static class ChangeString
    {
        public static string ReplaceThereSubstring(this String myString)
        {
           return myString.Replace("there","here");
        }
    }
```

but it always returns null.

Comment: No, that code won't return null. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I editted it. But I just saw that the String class is immutable.I don't know if I could do that.

Comment: You have to reassign it. `var a = a.ReplaceThereSubstring();`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Should the `var` really be there? This would define `a` by referencing `a`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: yeah, it should either be left away or have a different name. Didn't pay too much attention to it since it was meant to demonstrate the reassignment.

Comment: `string` is immutable hence use `a=a.ReplaceThereSubstring();`

Comment: @mathinvalidnik if any answer helped you, please accept it

Answer (score 2):

in that case you should do this to run your code:

```
string a = "Hello there"
a = a.ReplaceThereSubstring();
```

You can not replace string's value in extension method because strings are **immutable**

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify an existing string because [strings are immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx).

So an expression like `myString.Replace("there", "here");` will not alter the myString instance.

Your extension method is actually correct but you should use it in this way:

```
a = a.ReplaceThereSubstring();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result, of course:

```
string b = a.ReplaceThereSubString();
```